# Addition of webhooks in Gitlab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I want to do automatic build in Jenkins when code gets pushed into the Gitlab.
For the same doing webhooks configuration in Gitlab, but getting error :

> Url is blocked: Requests to the local network are not allowed.

Even not able to do the activity mentioned in the image :

[image]

I am not able to go to the admin area.

Comment: Can anyone explain what is the aim this default limitation?

Answer (score 2):

if you have the gitlab server locally

from doc

> This behavior can be overridden by enabling the option “Allow requests to the local network from web hooks and services” in the “Outbound requests” section inside the Admin Area > Settings (/admin/application_settings/network):

url to the entire article [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/webhooks.html)

Comment: Thanks, Hamza for the pro tip. I am migrating from the Bitbucket server to GitLab and this suggestion worked for me like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use the root login and check the outbound option, you should be good.
Let me know if you get any other error.
I had faced the same issue yesterday, but all good now.

Comment: I am using the web version, i dont have other credential other than mine. How to use the root login.

Kindly help, Struggling